# How do I load my pdf file into my modal when the button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button that, when clicked, opens a modal with pdf content. I have a list of these.

My problem is that when the browser loads the website it also loads all the pdf files. I want a specific pdf file to load only when I press a button that opens one specific modal.

```
<li>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2" style="border: 1px solid black; height:200px;">
            <img src="Images/ImmanuelKant.jpg" style="padding:5px;" height="198" width="150">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h2>Immanuel Kant</h2>
                    <h3>something</h3>
                    <p>

                    </p>


                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div style="display: block;" class="modal modal-wide fade in" id="läsModal8" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class=" modal-content">

                                <div class="modal-body">
                                   <iframe class="pdfContainer" src="ViewerJS/../Books/SomePdf.pdf" allowfullscreen="" webkitallowfullscreen="" height="700px" width="100%"></iframe>

                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="col-md-6">

                        sometext


                    <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immanuel_Kant" target="_blank">read about</a>

                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#läsModal8">
                        read
                    </button>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">

            </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
    <br>
    <hr style="border-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);">
    <br>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `src` attribute of the iframe in the modal. The urls of the pdf files can be stored in a custom attribute of the buttons, and if you have the iframe in an element (jquery or simple javascript), you can set its attributes as `src` too.
With js maybe it's the `myiframe.setAttribute('src','http://...')`, or with jquery it is something like this: `myiframe.attr('src','http://...')`.
The best solution I think, if you set the pdf url for each button as I mentioned above, and if you can use jquery, you add a piece of code to the page like this:

```
jQuery('.modalbutton').click(function(){
  var pdf = jQuery(this).attr('data-pdfurl');
  jQuery('iframe #modal').attr('src', pdf);
});
```

(this is just a "skeleton", it might not work correctly...)

Comment: Sorry it took some time but this worked great. Thank you very much!